# Why use the ctypes to pass the structure array with union , the value is incorrect?

Tags: python, ctypes

Current I tried to use the ctypes to pass the structure array with union, but the value is incorrect.

Below is the C file as below :

```
typedef struct ModbusNodeDef
{
    enum
    {
        kModebusNodeType_RtuSlave    = 0,
        kModebusNodeType_RtuMaster   = 1,
        kModebusNodeType_AsciiSlave  = 2,
        kModebusNodeType_AsciiMaster = 3,
        kModebusNodeType_TcpServer   = 4,
        kModebusNodeType_TcpClient   = 5,
    }       type;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            PlcPeriSerial   serial;
            uint8_t         addr;
        }   rtu_slave;
        struct
        {
            PlcPeriSerial   serial;
        }   rtu_master;
        struct
        {
            PlcPeriSerial   serial;
            uint8_t         addr;
        }   ascii_slave;
        struct
        {
            PlcPeriSerial   serial;
        }   ascii_master;
        struct
        {
            PlcPeriEth      eth;
            uint8_t         addr;
            uint16_t        local_port;
        }   tcp_server;
        struct
        {
            PlcPeriEth      eth;
            char*           remote_addr;
            uint16_t        remote_port;
        }   tcp_client;
    };
}ModbusNodeDef;

void modbus_test(ModbusNodeDef node_def[], int node_num)
{
    for(int i=0; i<node_num; i++)
        {
            printf("\ni: %d, type: %d\n", i, node_def[i].type);
            printf("\naddr: %d\n", node_def[i].tcp_server.addr);
            printf("\nlocal_port: %d\n", node_def[i].tcp_server.local_port);
        }
}
```

And the python part, I define the class and anonymous union, but the value is incorrect.

```
 class PlcPeri(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("netx", c_void_p),
        ("type_id", c_uint32),
        ("version", c_uint32),
        ("location", c_uint32),
        ("desc", c_char_p),
        ("desc_size", c_uint)
    ]

class PlcPeriEth(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("parent", PlcPeri)
    ]

class PlcPeriSerial(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("parent", PlcPeri)
    ]

class ModbusRtuSlaver(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("serial", PlcPeriSerial),
        ("addr", c_uint8),
    ]

class ModbusRtuMaster(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("serial", PlcPeriSerial)
    ]

class ModbusAsciiSlaver(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("serial", PlcPeriSerial),
        ("addr", c_uint8),
    ]

class ModbusAsciiMaster(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("serial", PlcPeriSerial)
    ]

class ModbusTcpServer(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("eth", PlcPeriEth),
        ("addr", c_uint8),
        ("local_port", c_uint16)
    ]

class ModbusTcpClient(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("eth", PlcPeriEth),
        ("remote_addr", c_char_p),
        ("remote_port", c_uint16)
    ]

class ModbusNode(Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ("rtu_slave", ModbusRtuSlaver),
        ("rtu_master", ModbusRtuMaster),
        ("ascii_slave", ModbusAsciiSlaver),
        ("ascii_master", ModbusAsciiMaster),
        ("tcp_server", ModbusTcpServer),
        ("tcp_client", ModbusTcpClient),
    ]  

def test():
   nodeCount = 2
    node_def = (ModbusNodeDef * nodeCount)()
    plc_peri = PlcPeri()
    plc_peri_eth = PlcPeriEth()
    plc_peri_eth.parent = plc_peri
    tcp_server = ModbusTcpServer()
    tcp_server.eth= plc_peri_eth
    tcp_server.addr = c_uint8(2)
    tcp_server.local_port = c_uint16(503)
    node_def[0].type = 4
    node_def[0].tcp_server = tcp_server
    node_def[1].type = 2
    tcp_server_01 = ModbusTcpServer()
    tcp_server_01.eth= plc_peri_eth
    tcp_server_01.addr = c_uint8(10)
    tcp_server_01.local_port = c_uint16(5020)
    node_def[1].tcp_server = tcp_server_01

    libc_modbus.modbus_test.argtypes = [POINTER(ModbusNodeDef), c_int]
    libc_modbus.modbus_test.restype = None
    libc_modbus.modbus_test(node_def, 2)
```

expected result should be

i: 0, type: 1
addr: 2
local_port: 503

i: 1, type: 2
addr: 10
local_port: 5020

but actual print as below

i: 0, type: 1
addr: 0
local_port: 0

i: 1, type: 0
addr: 2
local_port: 503

Answer (score 0):

The issue was closed, it caused by the PlcPeriSerial and PlcPeriEth defined as struct pointer, so it shoudl be used the POINTER(PlcPeriEth)
The PlcPeriEth defined as below in C File

```
typedef struct PlcPeriEth
{
    struct PlcPeri  parent;

    PlcPeriRet (*const create_tcp_client)   (struct PlcPeriEth* this, const char* remote_addr, uint16_t remote_port, int8_t* link_index);
    PlcPeriRet (*const create_tcp_server)   (struct PlcPeriEth* this, uint16_t local_port, uint8_t max_client_num, int8_t* link_index);
    PlcPeriRet (*const tcp_server_accept)   (struct PlcPeriEth* this, int8_t server_link_index, int8_t* link_index);
    PlcPeriRet (*const create_udp_client)   (struct PlcPeriEth* this, const char* remote_addr, uint16_t remote_port, int8_t* link_index);
    PlcPeriRet (*const create_udp_server)   (struct PlcPeriEth* this, uint16_t local_port, int8_t* link_index);
    PlcPeriRet (*const close_link)          (struct PlcPeriEth* this, int8_t link_index);
    PlcPeriRet (*const read)                (struct PlcPeriEth* this, int8_t link_index, int buf_size, uint8_t* data_buf, int* length_readed, int timeout_ms);
    PlcPeriRet (*const write)               (struct PlcPeriEth* this, int8_t link_index, int data_size, const uint8_t* data, int* length_writed);
}*PlcPeriEth;
```

so the python should used the POINTER(PlcPeriEth), such as:

```
class ModbusTcpServer(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [
        ("eth", POINTER(PlcPeriEth)),
        ("addr", c_uint8),
        ("local_port", c_uint16)
    ]
```